# Jquery passing data title to self

Tags: jquery

Currently I have this in my code to identify (this) in an html element.

```
var $self = $(self);
```

Using $self I then make my jquery calls like so:

```
$self.val('0'); or $self.val('1'); etc...
```

I also am able to get an element via jquery with this:

```
$('[data-title="printing"]').val()
```

my question is how would I make a call to an element using the self and also the data title field indicated above.
Something like this (obviously wrong syntax)

$self.('[data-title="printing"]').val()

EDIT: As requested here is the rest of the code:

I have an input element:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="getButtonDetails(this)" data-toggle="switch" data-title="printing" data-order="{{ $order->order_number }}" class="ct-primary" value="0" />
```

which calls getButtonDetails(this)

```
function getButtonDetails(elem){
                      var self = elem;
                      var $self = $(self);

                        console.log($self.data('order'));}
```

Comment: Is `$self` and `$('[data-title="printing"]')` two different elements? If so, where is `$self` placed relative to the other element (better to update your code with some relevant HTML).

Comment: @Mikey I updated it including the html.

Comment: why would you do it this way instead of using the existing `$` object? Or you could use `jQuery`? You could even do `$self = jQuery` and get more reliable results.

Comment: @Anthony cause I don't really know what I'm doing, I'm just getting started.  I'm using Jquery but how should I do it if this way isn't right?

Comment: `self` is a reference to `Window.self`. What are you actually wanting `$self` to be a reference to? The current context of the function, like `this`? I think `$(this)` usually works fine, but if you want it to have a simple variable name, you could do `$self = $(this);` but I would shy away from potentially reserved keywords like this and self (if nothing else, it can confuse others try to review your code). Maybe go with `$myself = $(this);` (not the best, I know)

Comment: @Anthony but here I am passing parameter (elem) this.  Then I make hte variable self to be that elem.  I got that off another thread here on so.

Comment: `var self = elem; var $self = $(self);` why do it this way? Why not just ` `var $self = $(elem);` Seems wackadoo to set `self` first if you are just going to use it to assign it to a different variable.

Comment: I don't get your question. _passing data title to self_ you don't need to pass anything as you already have the data attribute by either doing `$self.data('title')` or `elem.dataset.title`.

Comment: @Anthony as I said it's cause I got it off another thread here that said to do it that way.

Comment: @Mikey ok but how would I get the value of of this?  Means $self.data('title'.val()... something like that

Comment: @FabricioG `$self.data('title')` or `elem.dataset.title` would give you `printing` in your example. `$self.val()` would give you `0`. But as someone mentioned, you should do `var $self = $(elem)` instead of `var self = elem; var $self = $(self)`.

Comment: @Mikey ok I see where I messed up now.  So the reason I set self is because I have five inputs.  Each has a different data-title name.  So that is why I needed to find self.data('title') === 'printing' to get the value of that specific input.  I thought this was a straight forward question but I should have put all that.

Comment: @Anthony... $myself comment... ok got it, makes perfect sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check in condition if the attribute of element is equal to desired value then get the value of the element

```js
$("span").each(function() {

  var $self = $(this);

  if ($self.attr("data-title") == "span") {
    $self.css("color", "red")
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-title="span">red</span>
<span data-title="">not red</span>
```

Comment: The key difference between your code example and the OP's is you have `$self = $(this)`, while the OP is using `$self = $(self)`. Everything beyond that in your answer, I think, is just gravy.